# One application hits a request in another but the information is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, response

```
 public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var result = this.hardwareInfoManager.GetHardWareInfo();
            Log.Logger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = Configuration.GetValue<string>("HealthMonitorApplicationUrl");
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
                request.Content = new StringContent(serializedString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await client.PostAsync(url, request.Content));
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Log.Logger.Information(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                    if (response.Content != null)
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Information(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I send a request to url "http://localhost:5002/api/v1/healthmonitor".

It hits the method in the other application which is :

```
    [Route("/api/v1/healthmonitor")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveHardwareInfo(HardwareInfoDto hardwareInfoDto)
    {
        var result = await hardwareInfoManager.SaveHardwareInfo(hardwareInfoDto);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }
        else 
        {
            return BadRequest($"{result.Errors}");
        }
    }
```

But none of the information is populated. I also tried using Postman but to no avail.

Can you advise?

Comment: just going on a limb here, what happens if you change  `ReceiveHardwareInfo(HardwareInfoDto hardwareInfoDto)` to `ReceiveHardwareInfo(object hardwareInfoDto)`

Comment: Still empty unfortunately

Comment: What if you remove the `[Route("/api/v1/healthmonitor")]` tag and hit that endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Change the method in the controller to this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveHardwareInfo([FromBody] HardwareInfoDto hardwareInfoDto)
```